# SSL algorithms for embedded device

Tags: embedded, openssl

I have an SSL client on an embedded device with a slow ARM-CPU.

I am trying to speed up the SSL connection setup by shortening the cipherslist. Disabling DiffieHellman by adding !DH gave an improvement.

I wonder if there are other algorithms i could disable to improve the speed. Of course without big security tradeoffs.

Another possibility would be to switch to a different SSL library (gnutls, matrixssl, yaSSL etc.) What are your experience with other SSL libraries especially on embedded devices?

Comment: A simlar question but focusing on size of the binary is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414004/openssl-static-library-too-big-any-alternative-or-way-to-reduce-its-size

Answer (score 1):

CyaSSL has an great track record with embedded devices and has been used many times with ARM-enabled embedded devices.

As for speeding up the connection with CyaSSL, you can speed up public key operations with fast math (**--enable-fastmath**) which will make use of assembly optimizations to speed up your handshake time. You can also switch to a different cipher, such as **HC-128**, which is CyaSSL's fastest cipher ([a stream cipher](http://yassl.com/yaSSL/Blog/Entries/2010/8/25_The_Benefit_of_Stream_Ciphers.html)).

CyaSSL is also pretty portable out of the box. The [product page](http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/Products-cyassl.html) states that is supports the following OS's:

> Win32/64, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, ThreadX, VxWorks, FreeBSD, NetBSD,
>   OpenBSD, embedded Linux, Haiku, OpenWRT, iPhone (iOS), Android,
>   Nintendo Wii and Gamecube through DevKitPro, QNX, MontaVista, OpenCL,
>   NonStop, TRON/ITRON/µITRON, Micrium's µC/OS, FreeRTOS, Freescale MQX,
>   Nucleus

It's also got a really small footprint (<100kB), which is another plus.